# find and replace using macro in the subject of an active email

Tags: vba, outlook

I have an MIS that produces an automated email for Work instructions.  However I have manipulated the crystal report to make an order acknowledgement and would like to replace the words in the SUBJECT for `"Work Instruction '1234' 'date' etc"` with `"Order Acknowledgement '1234' 'date' etc".`

I want to click a macro button I have added to the 'compose email' screen to do this

Here is what I have tried, It currently doesn't work.

```
Sub OrderAck()
    Dim OrdAck As String
    Dim NewMail As Outlook.MailItem

    Set NewMail = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

    OrdAck = Replace(NewMail.Subject, "Works Instruction", "Order Acknowledgement")

    NewMail.Subject = OrdAck
    NewMail.Subject = Display

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try to debug the code? See [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

To Edit the subject line try the following

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub OrderAck()
    Dim olItem As Object
    Dim OrdAck As String
    Dim sNew As String
    Dim NewMail As Outlook.Application

    Set NewMail = Application
    Set olItem = NewMail.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)

    OrdAck = Replace(olItem.Subject, "Works Instruction", "Order Acknowledgement")

    sNew = OrdAck
    olItem.Subject = sNew
    olItem.Save
End Sub
```